# How to resize camera or gallery photo

Tags: java, android, image, camera, gallery

I choose a file from gallery or camera. Then I'll upload them to the server. But I can't reduce their size. Image quality does not matter. Can you tell me the best method? I'm a beginner and I don't know how to use the code. So please give details.

```
  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.myapplication.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Glide.with(this).load(currentPhotoPath).into(iv);

    } else if (requestCode == SELECT_A_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        selectedPhoto = data.getData();
        Glide.with(this).load(selectedPhoto).into(iv);

    }

 private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,SELECT_A_PHOTO);
}
```

[My file sizes look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUN4P.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.This method allows you to reduce the size.

```
// Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

[New image size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV6ge.png)

Answer (score 0):

This function takes in the image path and converts into a bitmap. 700 is the basic threshold for height/width set by me here. You can change it accordingly and create a scaled bitmap (The lower the number, lower is the image size). Each iteration of the while loop reduces the image to half. You can remodify it as per your requirement.

```
private Bitmap reduce_image_to_bitmap(String file_path){
    Bitmap bit_map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
    int h = bit_map.getHeight();
    int w = bit_map.getWidth();
    while(h > 700 || w > 700){
        h = h/2;
        w = w/2;
    }
    Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bit_map, w, h, false);
    return out;
}
```

Make sure to convert the bitmap to a file and then proceed to send the file to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library: [Compressor](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor)

- Compressor is a lightweight and powerful android image compression library. Compressor will allow you to compress large photos into smaller sized photos with very less or negligible loss in quality of the image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to process this image so that you can reduce the size but quality you can maintain. You need to run a background task so that during big image process device doesn't fizz.

Then you can show a progress dialog during this process just add this code into your onCreate activity.

```
  public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyProfileEidtActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");


    // just execute this process

    new ImageProcessing().execute("YOUR IMAGE PATH");

  }


 public class ImageProcessing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Image Processing");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Bitmap mainImage = null;
        Bitmap converetdImage = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        byte[] bt = null;
        String encodeString = null;
        try {
            mainImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strings[0]);

        /// 500 means image size will be maximum 500 kb

            converetdImage = getResizedBitmap(mainImage, 500);
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            converetdImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
            bt = bos.toByteArray();
            encodeString = Base64.encodeToString(bt, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodeString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String image) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        progressDialog.dismiss();

     // this image will be your reduced image path

    }
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

    float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize;
        height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
    } else {
        height = maxSize;
        width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
}
```